# What is the proper syntax for .find() in bs4?

Tags: python, html, css, syntax, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the bitcoin price off of coinbase and cannot find the proper syntax. When I run the program (without the line with question marks) I get the block of html that I need, but I don't know how to narrow down and retrieve the price itself. Any help appreciated, thanks.

```
    import requests
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

    url = 'https://www.coinbase.com/charts'
    data = requests.get(url)
    nicedata = data.text

    soup = BeautifulSoup(nicedata, 'html.parser')
    prettysoup = soup.prettify()


    bitcoin = soup.find('h4', {'class': 
    'Header__StyledHeader-sc-1q6y56a-0 hZxUBM 
    TextElement__Spacer-sc-18l8wi5-0 hpeTzd'})

    price = bitcoin.find('???')

    print(price)
```

[The attached image contains the html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fI4aa.png)

Comment: `price = bitcoin.text`

Comment: there are many `<h4>` with this class - `find()` gets only first one and it has text `Bitcoint`, not price from you image. You may need `find_all()` to get all items as  list. And later `for`-loop to check every element on list to get expected values.

Comment: it may be easier to get rows `<tr>` and later in rows search `<h4>`. This way you can organize data in list of lists or numpy.array or pandas.DataFrame

Comment: Read the BeautifulSoup docs, they’re quite good IMO. Are you looking for a guide to BeautifulSoup or something?

Answer (score 0):

To get text from item:

```
price = bitcoin.text
```

---

But this page has many items `<h4>` with this class but `find()` gets only first one and it has text `Bitcoin`, not price from your image. You may need `find_all()` to get list with all items and then you can use index `[index]` or slicing `[start:end]` to get some items, or  you can use `for`-loop to work with every item on list.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.coinbase.com/charts'
r = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

all_h4 = soup.find_all('h4', {'class': 'Header__StyledHeader-sc-1q6y56a-0 hZxUBM TextElement__Spacer-sc-18l8wi5-0 hpeTzd'})

for h4 in all_h4:
    print(h4.text)
```

---

It can be easier to work with data if you keep it in list of list or array or DataFrame. But to create list of lists it would be easier to find rows `<tr>` and inside every row search `<h4>`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.coinbase.com/charts'
r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')

all_tr = soup.find_all('tr')

data = []

for tr in all_tr:
    row = []
    for h4 in tr.find_all('h4'):
        row.append(h4.text)
    if row: # skip empty row
        data.append(row)

for row in data:
    print(row)
```

It doesn't need `class` to get all `h4`.

---

**BTW:** This page uses `JavaScript` to append new rows when you scroll page but `requests` and `BeautifulSoup` can't run `JavaScript` - so if you will need all rows then you may need `Selenium` to control web browser which runs `JavaScript`